# Pasar el id de un <table> a una funcion javascript para que haga pagination sobre la tabla

Tags: javascript, html5

Hola quiero pasar el id de un  a una función javascript llamada hacerPagination() para que haga el pagination sobre la tabla. Tengo entendido que no puedo pasar por parametro de la siguiente forma hacerPagination(String idTabla) en javascript. 
Tengo una carpeta llamada "js" y dentro de la misma el archivo "misFunciones.js" donde contiene la funcion hacerPagination(). Entonces yo quiero llamar a hacerPagination() desde el html y pasarle el id. Como podría hacerlo? aca les dejo el código de la función:

```js
function hacerPagination() {
  //get the table element
  var $table = document.getElementById("myTable"),
    // number of rows per page
    $n = 4,
    // number of rows of the table
    $rowCount = $table.rows.length,
    // get the first cell's tag name (in the first row)
    $firstRow = $table.rows[0].firstElementChild.tagName,
    // boolean var to check if table has a head row
    $hasHead = ($firstRow === "TH"),
    // an array to hold each row
    $tr = [],
    // loop counters, to start count from rows[1] (2nd row) if the first row has a head tag
    $i, $ii, $j = ($hasHead) ? 1 : 0,
    // holds the first row if it has a (<TH>) & nothing if (<TD>)
    $th = ($hasHead ? $table.rows[(0)].outerHTML : "");
  // count the number of pages
  var $pageCount = Math.ceil($rowCount / $n);
  // if we had one page only, then we have nothing to do ..
  if ($pageCount > 1) {
    // assign each row outHTML (tag name & innerHTML) to the array
    for ($i = $j, $ii = 0; $i < $rowCount; $i++, $ii++)
      $tr[$ii] = $table.rows[$i].outerHTML;
    // create a div block to hold the buttons
    $table.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "<div id='buttons'></div");
    // the first sort, default page is the first one
    sort(1);
  }

  // ($p) is the selected page number. it will be generated when a user clicks a button
  function sort($p) {
    /* create ($rows) a variable to hold the group of rows
     ** to be displayed on the selected page,
     ** ($s) the start point .. the first row in each page, Do The Math
     */
    var $rows = $th,
      $s = (($n * $p) - $n);
    for ($i = $s; $i < ($s + $n) && $i < $tr.length; $i++)
      $rows += $tr[$i];

    // now the table has a processed group of rows ..
    $table.innerHTML = $rows;
    // create the pagination buttons
    document.getElementById("buttons").innerHTML = pageButtons($pageCount, $p);
    // CSS Stuff
    document.getElementById("id" + $p).setAttribute("class", "active");
  }


  // ($pCount) : number of pages,($cur) : current page, the selected one ..
  function pageButtons($pCount, $cur) {
    /* this variables will disable the "Prev" button on 1st page
       and "next" button on the last one */
    var $prevDis = ($cur == 1) ? "disabled" : "",
      $nextDis = ($cur == $pCount) ? "disabled" : "",
      /* this ($buttons) will hold every single button needed
       ** it will creates each button and sets the onclick attribute
       ** to the "sort" function with a special ($p) number..
       */
      $buttons = "<input class='btnPage' type='button' value='&lt;&lt; Prev' onclick='sort(" + ($cur - 1) + ")' " + $prevDis + ">";
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $pCount; $i++)
      $buttons += "<input class='btnPage' type='button' id='id" + $i + "'value='" + $i + "' onclick='sort(" + $i + ")'>";
    $buttons += "<input class='btnPage' type='button' value='Next &gt;&gt;' onclick='sort(" + ($cur + 1) + ")' " + $nextDis + ">";
    return $buttons;
  }
}
```

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
     pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
  <%@ page import="ElRinconDelLector.com.ar.Clases.*"%>
    <%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
      <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
      <html>

      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Seccion libros</title>
        <%@include file="head.html"%>
      </head>

      <body>
        <%
      List<Libro> listaLibros = new ArrayList<Libro>();
      DaoLibro dl = new DaoLibro();
      DaoAutor ad = new DaoAutor();
      listaLibros = dl.obtenerLibrosTodos();
      String nombreAutor;
      String nombreCategoria;
      String nombreEditorial;
     %>
          <%@include file="navigation.html"%>
            <center>
              <h2>
                Seccion de libros
                </h1>
            </center>
            <div class="container">

              <form method="get" action="ServletLibro">
                <table class="miTabla" id="myTable">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Id libro</th>
                      <th>Imagen</th>
                      <th>Nombre</th>
                      <th>Autor</th>
                      <th>Descripcion</th>
                      <th></th>
                      <th></th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <%
          for (Libro libro : listaLibros) {
         %>

                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <%
            out.print(libro.getIdLibro());
           %>
                        </td>
                        <td><img class="img-fluid" src=<%out.print(libro.getUrlImagen());%>></td>
                        <td>
                          <%
            out.print(libro.getNombre());
           %>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <%
            out.print(nombreAutor = ad.obtenerAutorNombre(libro.getIdAutor()));
           %>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <%
            out.print(libro.getDescripcion());
           %>
                        </td>
                        <!-- <td><input type = "submit" id="btnSubmit" name="btnAdd" value="Agregar"></td> -->
                        <td>
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="" name="btnVerLibro">Ver</button>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="" name="btnModifyLibro">Modificar</button>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <%
          }
         %>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </form>

            </div>
            <%@include file="misScripts.html"%>
              <script type="text/javascript" src="js/misFunciones.js"></script>
              <script>
                hacerPagination("myTable")
              </script>
      </body>

      </html>
```

Comment: y tu html de ejemplo?

Comment: Perdon Ruslan soy nuevo en este foro y soy un poco lento, ahí edite mi pregunta y subí el html. El problema que tengo ahora es que al pulsar el botón siguiente del pagination no hace nada!

Answer (score 1):

Te equivocas, sí puedes pasar un parámetro dentro de la función, solo que JS no espera que lo entregues con el tipo de dato al no ser un lenguaje altamente tipado, la forma correcta de hacerlo es esta:

```
function hacerPagination(tableId){...}
```

Te dejo la explicación de como ejecutar la función desde el HTML dentro del código.

```js
function hacerPagination(tableId){ //Recibimos el id como parámetro en la función
 //get the table element
 var $table = document.getElementById(tableId), //Agregamos el parámetro que recibimos dinámicamente
  
 // number of rows per page
 $n = 4,
 // number of rows of the table
 $rowCount = $table.rows.length,
 // get the first cell's tag name (in the first row)
 $firstRow = $table.rows[0].firstElementChild.tagName,
 // boolean var to check if table has a head row
 $hasHead = ($firstRow === "TH"),
 // an array to hold each row
 $tr = [],
 // loop counters, to start count from rows[1] (2nd row) if the first row has a head tag
 $i,$ii,$j = ($hasHead)?1:0,
 // holds the first row if it has a (<TH>) & nothing if (<TD>)
 $th = ($hasHead?$table.rows[(0)].outerHTML:"");
 // count the number of pages
 var $pageCount = Math.ceil($rowCount / $n);
 // if we had one page only, then we have nothing to do ..
 if ($pageCount > 1) {
     // assign each row outHTML (tag name & innerHTML) to the array
     for ($i = $j,$ii = 0; $i < $rowCount; $i++, $ii++)
         $tr[$ii] = $table.rows[$i].outerHTML;
     // create a div block to hold the buttons
     $table.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend","<div id='buttons'></div");
     // the first sort, default page is the first one
     sort(1);
 }

 // ($p) is the selected page number. it will be generated when a user clicks a button
 function sort($p) {
     /* create ($rows) a variable to hold the group of rows
     ** to be displayed on the selected page,
     ** ($s) the start point .. the first row in each page, Do The Math
     */
     var $rows = $th,$s = (($n * $p)-$n);
     for ($i = $s; $i < ($s+$n) && $i < $tr.length; $i++)
         $rows += $tr[$i];
     
     // now the table has a processed group of rows ..
     $table.innerHTML = $rows;
     // create the pagination buttons
     document.getElementById("buttons").innerHTML = pageButtons($pageCount,$p);
     // CSS Stuff
     document.getElementById("id"+$p).setAttribute("class","active");
 }


 // ($pCount) : number of pages,($cur) : current page, the selected one ..
 function pageButtons($pCount,$cur) {
     /* this variables will disable the "Prev" button on 1st page
        and "next" button on the last one */
     var $prevDis = ($cur == 1)?"disabled":"",
         $nextDis = ($cur == $pCount)?"disabled":"",
         /* this ($buttons) will hold every single button needed
         ** it will creates each button and sets the onclick attribute
         ** to the "sort" function with a special ($p) number..
         */
         $buttons = "<input class='btnPage' type='button' value='&lt;&lt; Prev' onclick='sort("+($cur - 1)+")' "+$prevDis+">";
     for ($i=1; $i<=$pCount;$i++)
         $buttons += "<input class='btnPage' type='button' id='id"+$i+"'value='"+$i+"' onclick='sort("+$i+")'>";
     $buttons += "<input class='btnPage' type='button' value='Next &gt;&gt;' onclick='sort("+($cur + 1)+")' "+$nextDis+">";
     return $buttons;
 }
}
```

```html
<!-- Llamamos la función al hacer clic al botón-->
<button type="button" onclick="hacerPagination('myTable')">Hacer paginación</button>
```

Faltaría añadir la tabla al snippet para que funcione todo bien, si lo requieres puedo poner una tabla de ejemplo, realiza pruebas y me cuentas.

Espero haya sido de utilidad.

Comment: Gracias Jonathan por responder...pero no me funciona!, perdón me falto poner comillas simples en el snipet, ahora el pagination me lo muestra. pero al pulsar el botón para que me muestre la pagina 2..no me responde!

Comment: Cuidado que ese myTable debe estar dentro de comillas, ya que es un string.

Comment: Gracias Jonathan por responder...pero no me funciona!, perdón me falto poner comillas simples en el snipet, ahora el pagination me lo muestra. pero al pulsar el botón para que me muestre la pagina 2..no me responde! –

Comment: Ya sería cuestión de mirar el funcionamiento total del resto de código. Si subes el HTML al snippet probamos.

Comment: ok subo el html completo de todas formas!